# A regular expression to filter out repetitive numbers for R data frame columns

Tags: r, regex, dataframe, filter

I have a data frame with many columns and rows and I need to filter based on the value of two columns (Lat and Lon). I need a regular expression which

1. Removes any row for which either the Lat or Lon column does not have at least three decimal places. So the first row (human) would be filtered, because even though Lon has three decimal places, Lat does not.
2. Removes any row for which the decimal places are redundant. What I mean by redundant is there are three repeats of the same number continuing to the end. But if the redundancy starts after the third decimal, it doesn't matter. And if the redundancy is eventually followed by a different number, it doesn't matter.

```
Type <-c("human","camera","ebird","museum", "specimen", "gbif")
Lat <- c(34.67, 34.66,34.6666666, 34.666582, 34.56666, 34.586666)
Lon <- c(9.888,9.88,9.8761,9.888064, 9.78888,9.318888)
x = data.frame(cbind(Type,Lat,Lon))
```

Here's how each row would fare under the regex:

1. fails because Lat only has two decimal places, even though Lon passes.
2. fails because both rows only have two decimal places
3. fails because Lat repeats the same value, starting at the first decimal place, and the repetition continues to the end of the number.
4. Passes the regex
5. Fails because the repetitive number values starts at the second decimal places and continues for at least 3 repetitions all the way to the end
6. Passes the regex

So the resulting data frame from this regex filter would be:

```
Type <-c("museum","gbif")
Lat <- c(34.666582, 34.586666)
Lon <- c(9.888064, 9.318888)
x = data.frame(cbind(Type,Lat,Lon))
```

Comment: You have stored `lat` and `lon` as numbers. what if some lat/lon stored as `34.660` or `34.600` or `34.000` in all these cases extra 0s will be truncated automatically.  In all these cases, do you want to retain these or filter out?

Comment: `34.660` should pass this regex ex. Can we modify to make  `34.600` fail if both the Lat and Lon columns have trailing zeros (and only for the number `0`, not for other numbers)? So if Lat is `34.600` and Lon is `9.300`, it should fail. `34.000` would fail because the `0` repeats three times and nothing comes after the three repeating zeros.

Comment: 1) Why have you specified that `34.66` (2nd row Lat) fail then? when `34.66 == 34.660`?  Why do assume that `0` is non-existent?

Comment: What I am trying to explain is just change your `Lat` column with this one `Lat <- c(34.670, 34.660,34.6666666, 34.666582, 34.56666, 34.586666)` and then check the output of `x`

Comment: Because these are actual latitude and longitude values and `34.660` is a legitimate value for longitude, which is more accurate than `34.66` in the data set I'm getting this data frame from. So if the zero is expressly stated in the third decimal place I trust it as an accurate coordinate. I'm filtering out inaccurate coordinates. I don't trust coordinates with improbably repetitive decimal values, or lots of repeating zeros. I also need at least three expressly written decimal values for each Lat/Lon entry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function below will output the desired dataframe that you want. It accomplishes all of the requirements you stated above.

```
check.expressions <- function(data){
  data$pass <- FALSE
  for(i in 1:nrow(data)){
    if(nchar(str_extract(x$Lon[i], "(?<=\\.).*")) < 3 | nchar(str_extract(x$Lat[i], "(?<=\\.).*")) < 3){
     next 
    } else {
      unlist(str_split(str_extract(x$Lon[i], "(?<=\\.).*" ), "")) -> lon
      unlist(str_split(str_extract(x$Lat[i], "(?<=\\.).*" ), "")) -> lat
      if(lon[1] == lon[2] && lon[2] == lon[3]){
        if(length(lon) > 3){
          if(lon[3] != lon[length(lon)]){
            data$pass[i] <- TRUE
            next
          } else {
            next
          }
        }
        next
      }
      if(lat[1] == lat[2] && lat[2] == lat[3]){
        if(length(lat) > 3){
          if(lat[3] != lat[length(lat)]){
            data$pass[i] <- TRUE
            next
          } else {
            next
          }
        }
        next
      }
      if(length(lon) > 4){
        if(lon[2] == lon[3] && lon[3] == lon[4]){
          if(lon[4] != lon[length(lon)]){
            data$pass[i] <- TRUE
            next
          } else {
            next
          }
        }
      }
      if(length(lat) > 4){
        if(lat[2] == lat[3] && lat[3] == lat[4]){
          if(lat[4] != lat[length(lat)]){
            data$pass[i] <- TRUE
            next
          }
        }
      }
      data$pass[i] <- TRUE
    }
  }
  data[data$pass == TRUE, ] -> data
  return(data)
}
```

The function call being just:

```
check.expressions(x) -> x.out
```

which would produce:

```
> check.expressions(x) -> x.out
> x.out
    Type       Lat      Lon pass
4 museum 34.666582 9.888064 TRUE
6   gbif 34.586666 9.318888 TRUE
```